# How to remove hyperlinks from SharePoint 2010 workflow email body? Means can we send plain text email in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, multiple-lines-of-text

We have a SharePoint 2010 workflow, and in that we send the text of description field in SharePoint online list, which is "Multiple Lines Of Text" field that is set to "Plain Text". But in that text we have certain words like "B.Com", "B.Sc", "M.Sc", "M.Tech". And for that words we are getting hyperlink which we don't want. Any idea how can we remove that hyperlink. The field is already set to "Plain Text" and we tried using workflow variable also but no luck. Also can we create custom actions in SharePoint online for the same issue. Because for on-premises we can do that by visual studio solution. Any help would be appreciated.